# ListView with check box/checkedtextview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I want to recreate how the gmail conversation list looks where you check the box for multiple selections and click else where for single viewing like in the picture

[image]

I tried using `CheckedTextView` but there is no checkbox like I thought there would be, so I guess my first question is would I be looking at just a regular `CheckBox` and if it is just a check box will that still allow for single clicks where it does not affect the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout to the listview as each item and make the layout have a checkbox on the left and textview on the right that has on onClick function defined.